# Ubuntu is not detecting WiFi

Tags: wireless

I have recently installed ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1 but after installation ubuntu does not detect WiFi while windows does. I am using Lenovo Z51-70 laptop. Please mention whatever data you require in comments.Wireless Info Script is Attached herewith.
[Wireless Info Script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15186207/)

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks a lot!!! The edit worked for me.